# Rails ActiveRecord query - Best possible way to implement the query inside the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

```
SELECT  user_id, investments, expenditures
FROM    ( SELECT  user_id, SUM(amount) investments
          FROM    transactions
          where   beneficiary_id is not null
          group    by user_id) A JOIN ( SELECT  beneficiary_id, SUM(amount) expenditures
                                        FROM    transactions
                                                where   beneficiary_id is not null
                                                group   by beneficiary_id) B
ON      A.user_id = B.beneficiary_id"
```

What is the best possible way with which an active record method can be written using find method ? The idea here is to use less SQL and more rails active record methods. I know this can be implemented with find_by_sql but looking for a more rails way of doing this.

Transactions is a model with the following structure

txndate:datetime
user_id:integer
beneficiary_id:integer
amount:decimal, :precision => 14, :scale => 2

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, and little bit confused, but maybe you need just scopes?
http://edgerails.info/articles/what-s-new-in-edge-rails/2010/02/23/the-skinny-on-scopes-formerly-named-scope/index.html

Comment: closest answer. I still cannot implement that entirely.